# Duplicación de procesos al iniciar mi aplicación usando Pyqt6 y multiprocessing

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv, pyqt6

Estoy creando una aplicación sencilla usando Pyqt6, opencv y el modulo de multiprocessing, con pyqt6 creo la interfaz y obtengo frames que luego envió a el process para su procesamiento con cv2. Funciona Bien, **el problema es que a veces se duplica el proceso** y consume el doble de recursos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en el que esta construido mi codigo es necesaria, este es un ejemplo simplificado de un codigo mas extenso y encontre que esta parte causa los problemas.

```
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
import multiprocessing
import time


class VideoThread(QThread):
    frame_signal = pyqtSignal(object)  # Señal para emitir frames

    def __init__(self, input_queue, output_queue, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.output_queue = output_queue
        self.is_running = False

    def run(self):
        self.is_running = True
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while self.is_running:
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if not ret:
                break

            if not self.input_queue.full():
                self.input_queue.put(frame)

            time.sleep(0.02)  # Descanso para evitar el uso excesivo de la CPU

        cap.release()
        
class VideoProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, input_queue, output_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.output_queue = output_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.input_queue.empty():
                frame = self.input_queue.get()
                # Aquí puedes realizar el procesamiento de la imagen con OpenCV
                # Por ejemplo, podrías convertir la imagen a escala de grises
                gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                # Emitir el frame procesado a la cola de salida
                self.output_queue.put(gray_frame)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.processor_input_queue = self.manager.Queue()
        self.processor_output_queue = self.manager.Queue()

        self.processor_process = None
        self.video_thread = None

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Pyqt6 aplicacion")
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        start_button = QPushButton("Iniciar", self)
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_video_thread)
        layout.addWidget(start_button)

        stop_button = QPushButton("Detener", self)
        stop_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_threads)
        layout.addWidget(stop_button)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        
        self.timer.start(50)  # Actualizar cada 50 milisegundos

    def start_video_thread(self):
        if self.video_thread is None or not self.video_thread.isRunning():
            # Inicializamos el hilo con las colas de entrada y salida del proceso
            self.processor_process = VideoProcess(self.processor_input_queue, self.processor_output_queue)
            self.video_thread = VideoThread(self.processor_input_queue, self.processor_output_queue)
            self.processor_process.start()
            self.video_thread.start()

    def update_frame(self):
        while not self.processor_output_queue.empty():
            processed_frame = self.processor_output_queue.get()

            qt_image = QImage(processed_frame.data, processed_frame.shape[1], processed_frame.shape[0],
                            processed_frame.strides[0], QImage.Format.Format_Grayscale8)
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qt_image)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def stop_threads(self):
        if self.video_thread is not None and self.video_thread.isRunning():
            self.video_thread.is_running = False
            self.video_thread.quit()
            self.video_thread.wait()

        if self.processor_process is not None and self.processor_process.is_alive():
            self.processor_process.terminate()
            self.processor_process.join()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            # Terminate the process and close the PyQt6 application gracefully
            print("Final del código")
            self.stop_threads()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Excepción en stop_threads: {e}")

    




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Estuve buscando soluciones y encontré que es posible que el al iniciar el script se cree un proceso que sea implícito del modulo multiprocessing, lo cual ya pude comprobar que no es, dado que en algunas ocasiones cuando cierro todas las pestañas de mi administrador de tareas y luego inicio el script solamente se usan dos procesos, el de procesamiento de imágenes y el de Pyqt6 aplication. Por lo que deduzco que el doble proceso no debería ocurrir y
pude correr el mismo código con un 15% de cpu total, aunque solo unas pocas veces.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
adjunto la prueba de que la aplicacion funciona solamente usando dos procesos, uno el de la interfaz y otro del procesamiento de imagenes

Comment: Les agradezco la ayuda, estoy iniciando en el diseño de aplicaciones :)

Answer (score 0):

Actualizacion: por si a alguien le sirve :)
el problema estaba en

```
self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
self.processor_input_queue = self.manager.Queue()
self.processor_output_queue = self.manager.Queue()
```

solo se cambia a

```
self.processor_input_queue = self.multiprocessing.Queue()
self.processor_output_queue = self.multiprocessing.Queue()
```